# Can't intellisense include Type script enum reverse mapping

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

For example

```
enum Enum {
  A = 2
}

const n = Enum.A
const a = Enum[2]
```

Intellisense / completion is provided for the .A but not the [2]

Is this because conpletion is not trigguered by [ like it is for .? Or is just not working at all?

Comment: In my copy of VSCode using typescript 2.4.1, `n` is inferred as `Enum` and `a` is correctly inferred as `string`. What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Aha! You've shown me the error of my thinking. To my mind the values are a finite set of values not a number. hence I was expecting the intellisense to to provide a list of those values and redline any numbers not in the set. I wanted that to be shown as I typed Enum.[

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I guess it would make sense if the type of `a` was inferred to be just those strings instead of any string. Perhaps in a future version of typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't get intellisense by using [] operator (in typescript).

But you always can use Enum[Enum.A] which will provide you the same result and you can still get the intellisense from Enum.A:

```
enum Enum {
  A = 2
}

console.log(Enum.A); // 2
console.log(Enum[Enum.A]); // A
```

Comment: Thanks for that. See my reponse to Duncan's comment on my question - I was over thinking it.